Intel 9260 Wireless Card not working after 24.04.1 upgrade
After the upgrade the Wireless Network Card no longer works so I'm using Wired until that can be sorted out.
Details as follows:
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 5(802.11ac) Wireless-AC 9x6x [Thunder Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:df000000-df003fff

I think this was working after the upgrade but there were issues with some packages and I was requested to run command "sudo apt-get install -f" and this found Obsolete packages. I was requested to run "sudo apt autoremove" and perhaps all my issues stem from this.
I tried reinstalling Intel packages but still no joy.
See errors in:
grep iwl /var/log/syslog
2024-09-02T13:02:52.018127+01:00 david-N7x0WU kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-30.ucode failed with error -2
2024-09-02T13:02:52.018129+01:00 david-N7x0WU kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
2024-09-02T13:02:52.018131+01:00 david-N7x0WU kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-30
2024-09-02T13:02:52.018136+01:00 david-N7x0WU kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-9260-th-b0-jf-b0-46
2024-09-02T13:02:52.018243+01:00 david-N7x0WU kernel: iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

Kernel in use as follows:
uname -r
5.13.0-30-generic
ls /lib/modules/5.13.0-30-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/
dvm  iwlwifi.ko  mvm

Also tried reinstalling Linux firmware:
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-firmware
[sudo] password for david: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/480 MB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 171090 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-firmware (20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.2) over (20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.2) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-so-a0-hr-b0-73.ucode.zst.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-firmware_20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)


I suggest checking what you're actually running, as you mention 5.15 which was a Ubuntu 21.10 kernel (https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-announce/2021-October/000274.html) and not a 22.04 or jammy kernel. You also mention a 22.04.1 upgrade which was back in 2022 (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/08/12/ubuntu-22-04-1-lts-released/).  Please check your details and clarify

I checked a detail in your paste, and your package details don't match 22.04 (linux-firmware | 20220329.git681281e4-0ubuntu3.14 | jammy-security is NOT what you pasted at all), instead yours looks more like linux-firmware | 20240318.git3b128b60-0ubuntu2.2  | noble-updates, so your details show 21.10, 22.04 & 24.04 now.

Combination of these got me back in. I'm assuming the update of the kernel was required.
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-image-`uname -r`
sudo apt --fix-broken install

Updated kernel:
uname -r
6.8.0-41-generic

cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS"


I have a similar issue https://askubuntu.com/questions/1525695/no-wi-fi-adapter-found-error-after-upgrade-from-22-04-4-to-24-04-1 but switching to this kernel did not solve the WiFi issue. Did you do something else too

I'm going to assume from this answer that the package linux-modules for the kernel didn't install during the upgrade, which would mean most of the modular drivers were missing.

You can run
sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi

to learn more about the specific error.
Like you, I had futzed with reinstalling the firmware and linux-module-extras for my kernel version. But, when I finally broke down and followed the advice in the error message (which seemed overly manual) it worked.
My error message:
[   21.053604] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[...]
[   21.055296] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[   21.055300] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-30
[   21.055303] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46
[   21.055307] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

The solution was based on this post. I will try to provide more details pertaining only to what I think is your issue.
Notice that it states which versions are acceptable. I had those. But "error -2" loading them. So I cloned the repo mentioned and copied the max supported version over the existing one.
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
sudo cp linux-firmware/iwlwifi-9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode /lib/firmware/

The, most people will tell you to restart. If you're sick of that, you can reload with modprobe.
sudo modprobe -v  -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi

The first line removes it, the second reloads it. The v flag is to make it verbose because I like chatty tools. :)
It should be working. Rerun
sudo dmesg | grep iwlwifi

After the old error, you should see a happy message along the lines of
[ 1117.810409] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.7e3e4b69.0 9000-pu-b0-jf-b0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1117.839047] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x318

I hope this helps you and good luck!
