No Wi-Fi Adapter Found error after upgrade from 22.04.4 to 24.04.1
I upgraded my Thinkpad T15g Gen 2i from Ubuntu 22.04.4 to 24.04.1 and after that there is no wifi nor bluetooth.

Here is the output of sudo lshw -class network
*-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) AX210/AX1675* 2x2 [Typhoon Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ae200000-ae203fff

Here is the output of lspci -nnv
$ sudo lspci -nnv


<snipped/>
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6E(802.11ax) AX210/AX1675* 2x2 [Typhoon Peak] [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0020]
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255, IOMMU group 18
    Memory at ae200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
    <snipped/>

Additional information:

The upgrade was interrupted by accident and that destroyed the grub
config. I fixed the grub config and then resumed the upgrade.
The kernel version in use is 5.14.0-1056-oem

hostnamectl gives me
$ hostnamectl | grep Kernel
          Kernel: Linux 5.14.0-1056-oem

uname -r gives me
$ uname -r 
5.14.0-1056-oem

$ ll /boot/vmlinuz*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Sep  4 10:25 /boot/vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8933184 Dec 16  2022 /boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-1056-oem
-rw------- 1 root root 14944648 Jul  5 14:42 /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 14948744 Aug  2 20:09 /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Sep  4 14:42 /boot/vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic


I also switched to 6.8.0-41-generic using the advanced options for ubuntu in grub, but that hasn't changed the "No Wi-Fi Adapter Found" message
sudo dmesg | grep wl


returns nothing
grep iwl /var/log/syslog

2024-09-22T18:07:20.275362+05:30 alok-ThinkPad-T15g-Gen-2i snap-store[3750]: not handling error download-failed for action refresh: E: The repository 'https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod jammy Release' does not have a Release file.#012W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.#012W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/i18n/Translation-en_US.UTF-8' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'sutton.simon/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://lenovo.archive.canonical.com noble InRelease' doesn't have the component 'sutton.simon' (component misspelt in sources.list?)#012E: The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.#012W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.#012W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.#012W: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key FBA0C227099A5360635E3D9152165BD6B9BA26FA uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)
What are the recommended steps to diagnose and fix this issue?
Not being a hardware person I do not know what other information to provide, I will keep appending information to this question based on the feedback received.
Thanks in advance for the help.

please edit to include results from terminal for sudo dmesg | grep iwl

add the output of sudo dmesg | grep iwl - it returns no records

Are you using dual boot? For me it worked to shutdown Windows holding shift during while pressing the Turn Off button. I think there is also a way for fixing this behaviour for Windows permantently.
I am on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS running a 6.8.0-40-generic kernel.

Thank you. This is working for me also on Ubuntu 24.10.

Have you an earlier version than 5.14 in your advanced options or is that the earliest kernel?
Any errors if you run these commands:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt-get install--reinstall linux-firmware
What is the output of:
grep iwl /var/log/syslog
Have you Synaptics Package Manager? Have used this sometimes to look at broken kernels.
Not an expert by any means and only have learned by being in similar situations before.

I added the output of grep iwl /var/log/syslog - part of it - probably relevant - is The repository 'https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi/ubuntu noble Release' does not have a Release file.#012W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.#012W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.#012W: https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/openshot.developers/ppa/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease: Signature by key FBA0C227099A5360635E3D9152165BD6B9BA26FA uses weak algorithm (rsa1024)

Original poster here, posting what finally worked for me. YMMV.
There was another update which I installed on 22-Sep-2024 which installed the kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
I switchted to this kernel via the grub options (default was still 5.14.0-1056-oem and was leading to missing wifi)
After booting with 6.8.0-45-generic
$ ll /boot/vmlinuz*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Sep 22 18:20 /boot/vmlinuz -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8933184 Dec 16  2022 /boot/vmlinuz-5.14.0-1056-oem
-rw------- 1 root root 14944648 Jul  5 14:42 /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-40-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 14948744 Aug  2 20:09 /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 14948744 Aug 30 14:32 /boot/vmlinuz-6.8.0-45-generic
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       24 Sep 22 18:20 /boot/vmlinuz.old -> vmlinuz-6.8.0-41-generic

wi-fi is now available. Hope this helps others as well.
